# What Exactly does => mean?

Tags: typescript

For some reason it is almost impossible to search for '=>'
Can anyone explain exactly what it means and when it is used?
Thank you!

Comment: It's an arrow function as documented in the language specification for TypeScript in 4.9.2: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf#page63

Comment: This video explains the reason why you need it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a lambda function and is used in TypeScript to maintain scope. In JavaScript `this` does not always refer to the scope you have defined it in, but is dependent on how the method is called. For example [prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) may override what `this` refers to.

To combat this, an easy trick is to copy your scope in a variable (say `self`) and use this variable wherever you want to access the scope.

The lambada function in TypeScript does this for you, you're no longer required to do scope copying yourself.

Example:

```
class Example {
    aMethod = () => {
     // in here 'this' will always refer to the class scope
    }
}
```

[Demo on Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Example%20%7B%0A%09aProp%3a%20string;%0A%09%0A%09constructor%28%29%7B%0A%09%09this.aProp%20=%20%22World%22;%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09nonScopeSafeMethod%28%29%7B%0A%09%09alert%28%22Hello%20%22%20+%20this.aProp%20%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09scopeSafeMethod%20=%20%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09alert%28%22Hello%20%22%20+%20this.aProp%20%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20e1%20=%20new%20Example%28%29;%0Ae1.nonScopeSafeMethod.call%28window%29;%0Ae1.scopeSafeMethod.call%28window%29;).

Comment: +1. Also... when you are searching for this in the documentation, it is typically called an "Arrow Function" in TypeScript. It can also be used as a more terse syntax for defining a function even if you aren't concerned about scope.